# Python - readlines

Tags: python

Is there a way I can just have python read lines and only use the first 10 characters and then assign them to a variable?

```
Remove_example= 'example'
Remove_at= '@'
#Remove_Agent='

filepath = 'Older WinCollect Agents on Version 728.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   print(line[0][10])
   cnt = 1
   while line:
       print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip(),).replace(str(Remove_example),'').replace(str(Remove_at),''))
       line = fp.readline()
       cnt += 1
```

I don't want to put static remove line variables

Comment: you can index a string- line[0:9] might be what you need?

Comment: Can you show example input and expected output?

Comment: Is it intentional that you handle the first line differently than the rest? In the first `print` call, you index the line twice - while this is syntactically allowed, it will fail, because the result of indexing with `[0]` would be a single character, and trying to index that with `[10]` will cause index out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_line_fronts(filepath: str) -> list:
    """Get list of first 10 characters in each line in a file."""
    line_fronts = []
    with open(filepath, "r") as fh:
        for line in fh:
            line_fronts.append(line[:10])
    return line_fronts


filepath = 'Older WinCollect Agents on Version 728.txt'
for line_front in get_line_fronts(filepath):
    # do whatever
```

Comment: This answers takes it a bit far, and is incomplete: First, you are generating a new list, which can be quite wasteful - the original code just processed everything in place. Secondly, it was not clear whether different processing was required for the first line or not (and the OP did not clarify, despite my request). Next, you ignored the `replace` calls in the original code. Finally, while you answer is correct (under some assumption about the intent), it could have been made a one-liner with comprehension. I would have not written this answer, because the OP's intent is just unclear.

Comment: This guy is not ready for production level code. The answer is educational, and I separated the functionality he had trouble understanding into a function for that reason. I could have made it return an interable instead of a list of course for efficiency...but was not sure how many new concepts to present a beginner with. Making it a list comprehension would have made it perhaps even more obscure to the OP.